# OperationalError Exception Value: no such column: registration_employeeregistration.Site_id

Tags: django

I have two models one is configration. The code of first model is as follow

```
enter code here
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class AddSite(models.Model):
    site = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Site')
    def __str__(self):
      return '{site}'.format(site=self.site)
class AddDepartment(models.Model):
    Department = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Department')
    def __str__(self):
      return '{Depart}'.format(Depart=self.Department)
class AddDesignation(models.Model):
    Designation = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Designation')
    def __str__(self):
      return '{Desig}'.format(Desig=self.Designation)
class AddCategory(models.Model):
    Category = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Category')
    def __str__(self):
       return '{Category}'.format(Category=self.Category)
class Rate(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(AddSite,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(AddCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=False)
    rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=False)
    def __str__(self):
       return '{site}'.format(site =self.site)
```

second models is employee registration

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from configration.models import AddSite, AddDepartment, AddCategory, AddDesignation
# Create your models here.


class EmployeeRegistration(models.Model):
#Departmental Details

EmpId = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='EmpId')
Site = models.ForeignKey(AddSite,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Site')
Department = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Department')
Category = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Category')
Designation = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Designation')
PfAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
EsiAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
Uan = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = False,verbose_name='Uan')
Pf = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = False,verbose_name='Pf')
AttendenceAward = models.BooleanField(default = True)
AttendenceAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
ProfesionalTax = models.BooleanField(default = False)
Rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = False)
# Personal Details
Name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Name')
Father = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Father')
Dob = models.DateField()
Gender = models.BooleanField(default = True)
MaritalStatus = models.BooleanField(default = True)
Address = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Address')
Aadhar = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
pan = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Status = models.CharField(blank = False,max_length=10,verbose_name='Status')
Doj = models.DateField(default = date.today)
Doe = models.DateField(blank = True,verbose_name = 'Doe',null = True)
```

makemigration and migrate work succesfully .But when i click on employee registration tab in admin panel it gives error like this
[image: error after clicking on employee registration in admin panel]

Comment: Check if you have saved the models.py file sucessfully. And make sure you migrate the right app.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i Overcome on my error. I just deleted My all migrations and database too.After that i gived some commands like.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
python manage.py runserver
```

and it worked successfully

But now i want to know that is it any way to overcome on this sitution without loosing database or without deleting database.